# Get table data using entity framework using vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I am using this code to retrieve a table record from a table, I want to fill every cell data in a separate text box, what I can do next?

```
      Dim match = From p In students_entities.StudentsInformations
                                    Where p.ID = id
                                    Select p 
txtfirstName.text=????
```

Comment: what exactly do u use? or do u need? asp?

Comment: I am using vb.net code @Roar

Comment: I see, but what do u need to do with ur data?

Comment: I want for example retrieve the first name of a student who  has id=1, when I use the previous statement it will retrieve a student record, how can I get his first name from the retrieved record?

Comment: `txtfirstName.Text = p.First().FirstName` assuming there is a match and you want to show the first match only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case when u select by id there is only one record should be, so u can do this

```
Dim match = (From p In students_entities.StudentsInformations
                                    Where p.ID = id
                                    Select p).FirstOrDefault
If match IsNot Nothing Then
   txtfirstName.text= match.FirstName
End If
```

or

```
Dim match = students_entities.StudentsInformations.FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.ID = id)
If match IsNot Nothing Then
   txtfirstName.text= match.FirstName
End If
```

Comment: @Alaa, keep in mind that second one will be better about performance, NOT IN THIS ONE, but in case it's some collection. So my tip: always use second approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell the EF that you want First row. Use the FirstOrDefault or Single function.

```
Dim match = From p In students_entities.StudentsInformations
                                Where p.ID = id
                                Select p 
txtfirstName.text= match.FirstOrDefault().name
```